# How to merge 2 objects Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Im have a small problem with proccessing arrays
I have data that I receive by API request

[image]

I need to check if category.parent_id = category.id
If this expression is executed
Then take the title of that row and put instead of parent_id
And the display the category.title

[image]

Im try different ways to solved this problem but i dont have any results
This is my code

```
                                    <tr v-for="(category, $index) in categories">
                                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                        <td>{{category.title}}</td>
                                        <td v-for="item in category['id']" v-if="item === category.parent_id">true</td>
                                        <td>{{category.created_at | moment("DD, MMMM, YYYY")}}</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>

2: {id: 8, title: "test2", alias: "test2-5e80113c71e4f", parent_id: null, keywords: "test2",…}
```

id: 8
title: "test2"
alias: "test2-5e80113c71e4f"
parent_id: null
keywords: "test2"
description: null
created_at: "2020-03-29T04:00:00.000000Z"
updated_at: "2020-03-29T04:00:00.000000Z"
3: {id: 10, title: "test4", alias: "test4-5e80116ab3b6c", parent_id: 7, keywords: "test4",…}
id: 10
title: "test4"
alias: "test4-5e80116ab3b6c"
parent_id: 7
keywords: "test4"
description: null
created_at: "2020-03-29T04:00:00.000000Z"
updated_at: "2020-03-29T04:00:00.000000Z"
4: {id: 11, title: "test5", alias: "test5-5e80168707b53", parent_id: null, keywords: "test5",…}
id: 11
title: "test5"
alias: "test5-5e80168707b53"
parent_id: null
keywords: "test5"
description: null
created_at: "2020-03-29T04:00:00.000000Z"
updated_at: "2020-03-29T04:00:00.000000Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use v-if and v-for on the same element. Best to put the v-if on a parent element.
After that, try to put this:

```
<tr v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
  <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{category.title}}</td>
  <td v-if="category.parent_id">{{ getParent(category.parent_id) }}</td>
  <td>{{ new Date(category.created_at).toLocaleString('ru-RU')}}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

And method:

```
getParent(childrenParentId) {
  // Check if exist parent or was deleted
  return this.categories.find(cat => childrenParentId === cat.id)
    ? this.categories.find(cat => childrenParentId === cat.id).title
    : "Parent was deleted and not exist";
}
```

Maybe its better to add a method with that code and call when render.

Find search first occurrence in your array of dicts and return that object.

Its important that if not exist parent will crash (you cant search ['title'] of undefined) so you will have to delete in cascade parent to childrens or remove in childrens that parent.

Codesandbox with test working:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-bas-6uhkx

Comment: Nice try but u r right im have error title undefined
Anyway thanks for help

Comment: Can you share JSON of 2 "category" in categories to test? Write manually its a bit hard. I checked code and clean a bit. Try it again if you can

Comment: Awesome thanks for help im 2 days trying to solved this problem